# How to convert Word or Number to list of Letters or Numbers?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm new for C#, but have some basic question:

I need to convert some words, for example: "Hello"(string) to list of letters" "H","e","l","l","o".
Or Number 3242, to list or array of numbers: [3,2,4,2].

How to do that?
And how after that I can change any number or letter in lists?
In Python its very easy. But in C# I don't know what to do.

Please provide LOGICAL and EASY solution. I don't need some 50 lines script which using 20 functions. I'm interested in basic understanding of that process with easy solution, if it existing.

Thank you guys,
P.S: i'm using    .Net 3.1

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "list". In Python, nearly anything is a list. In C# you have arrays, and complex object types like IEnumerable, Collection<T>, List<T>, and many more. What are you going to use the list for? That will help determine what you need...

Comment: After all, you have a string. That, by definition, is a list of characters. You can access a string like an array. `var s = "Hello"; Console.WriteLine(s[3]);`.

Comment: Do you know how to declare an array? Use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prasad already told you what you have to use, Let me give you some examples about how you going to do it:

## For String Type

Lets say there is a `string`:

```
string text = ".Net is Awesome";
```

To store this `string` as `char[]`:

```
char[] CharArray = text.ToCharArray();
```

To store this `string` as `List<char>`:

```
List<char> CharArray = text.ToCharArray().ToList();
```

Interestingly, for `string` Type variable you can directly use `.ToList()`:

```
List<char> CharArray = text.ToList();
```

## For Int Type

Now lets say you have an `int`:

```
int num = 123456;
```

To store this `int` as `char[]`:

```
char[] numArray = num.ToString().ToCharArray(); //Stored as char array no arithematic operation can be done.
```

### Using Convert.ToInt32()

To store this `int` as `int[]`:

```
int[] numArray = num.ToString().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray(); //Arithematic Operations allowed
```

To store this `int` as `List<int>`:

```
List<int> numArray = num.ToString().Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList(); //Arithematic Operations allowed
```

### Using int.Parse()

To store this `int` as `int[]`:

```
int[] numArray = num.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray(); //Arithematic Operations allowed
```

To store this `int` as `List<int>`:

```
List<int> numArray = num.ToString().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToList(); //Arithematic Operations allowed
```

Comment: I'm actually not surprised that it did not work. after i'm creating loop "foreach (int item in numArray)" its not printing every single Number in loop, its just printing in stead of 5 -> 53. Which is some crap element number or something else.  When you suggest those kind of solutions can you be more specific? since i mention that i'm a beggner

Comment: What part of the given code is not working for you. Apart from int.Parse() where I did not casted char to a string type (which I already Corrected), everything is working fine.

Comment: @Sergey here is an example if you really want to get *spoonfed*: https://rextester.com/QYBTKZ42704

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ToCharArray()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.tochararray?view=net-5.0#System_String_ToCharArray) function to convert input string to character array.
If it is a type other than string then first convert it to String

> Copies the characters in this instance to a Unicode character array.

```
var input = "Hello world";
if(input is string)  //Convert word to an array of char
     return input.ToCharArray();
if(input is int) //Convert Number to an array of char
     return input.ToString()  //First convert number to string
          .Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())) //Iterate over each digit and convert to int.
          .ToArray(); //Convert IEnumerable to Array
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code

```
var inputStringData = "Hello";//string
var charArray = inputStringData.ToCharArray() ;


var inputNumberData = 3242;//Number
int[] result = inputNumberData.ToString().Select(o => Convert.ToInt32(o) - 48).ToArray();
```